# Showing that the identity component of a linear algebraic group is a closed normal subgroup

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, normal-subgroups

Recall that a topological space is called connected if it cannot be expressed as the unsion of two disjoint non-empty open subsets. Every topological space admits a partition into its connected components, which are the maximal connected subspaces. For a linear algebraic group $G$, let $G^0$ denote the connected component (with respect to the Zariski topology) which contains the identity element $e \in G$. I want to show, that $G^0 \subset G$ is a Zariski closed normal subgroup.

**My idea:**
First i try showing, that $G^0$ is a normal subgroup. We fix an element $h \in G^0$ and consider the map $L_h: G \to G, A \mapsto hA$. This map is continious and hence maps components to components. Now we consider the image of $G^0$. For the identity element $e \in G^0$ we have $L_h e = h e = h$, thus $G^0$ maps to itself. We see, that $G^0$ must be closed under multiplication.
We now consider the inverse of $L_h$ given by $L_{h^{-1}}$ an note that $G^0$ is the only component it sends to $G^0$. Let $H$ be the component containing $h^{-1}$. Since $L_hh^{-1} = h h^{-1} = e \in G^0$ we see that $L_h(H) \subset G^0$. Thus $H=G^0$ and $h^{-1} \in G^0$. It follows that $G^0$ is a subgroup.

As for the normality: Let $g \in G$ and as above we now consider the continious map $C_g: G \to G, A \mapsto gAg^{-1}$. Since again for $e \in G^0$ we have $C_ge = g e g^{-1} = e \in G^0$, this map sends $G^0$ to itself. Thus $G_g(G^0) = gG^0 g^{-1} \subset G^0$ and hence $G^0$ is normal.

I now have two **problems**: *First* is that im not fully sure, this proof works, since it kinda depends on the fact, that components and path components coincide. And *second*, im stuck with the part, proofing that $G^0$ is Zariski-closed. And then there is like a *third* extra question, if this statement also holds true for subgroups $H^0 \subset H \subset G$?

Comment: Where exactly do you think you use the fact that components and path components coincide? I don't see any issues with your proof

Comment: Regarding your second question, a connected component of a space is necessarily a closed subset of that space.

Comment: Regarding your third question, I think we need the additional assumption that $H$ is a closed subset of $G$.

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting, my first two problems have been cleared now! Regarding the third question, if i have a subgroup $H \subset G$, would this proof still work to at least show that $H^0$ is a normal subgroup in $H$?